# Could not find com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.3-SNAPSHOT

Tags: android, picasso

I want to compile with `com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.3-SNAPSHOT`. But i got this error:

```
Error:Could not find com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.3-SNAPSHOT.
Required by:
    familywall-android:app:unspecified
<a href="searchInBuildFiles">Search in build.gradle files</a>
```

Have someone experienced something similar?

Comment: 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso-pollexor:2.5.3-SNAPSHOT' try using this in your dependencies

Comment: @Sushrita , got the same error

Comment: Is there any specific reason fo rusing picasso-snapshot?

Comment: yes, see my answer to @David Gordon

Comment: Do you have `maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/' }` in your repositories (in your build.gradle)?

Comment: @Eric Cochran , is working too, with your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the .jar [here](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/squareup/picasso/picasso/2.5.3-SNAPSHOT/), the last version is 21. It worked!

Answer (score 16):

The Picasso snapshot version you mentioned is not available in the standard maven repo. In your build.gradle add the following dependency to your dependencies block:

```
dependencies {
    // 2.5.3 is no longer updated.
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
    //...
}
```

and in the repositories block add

```
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/' }
    //...
}
```

Comment: Now if you want to use it make sure your package name is updated as well; picasso now has `picasso3` package: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/squareup/picasso3/

Comment: Latest dependency is now `com.squareup.picasso3:picasso:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT`. Note the package name change.